# JavaScript prototype of function not working properly

Tags: javascript, function-prototypes

I`ve made a prototype for "[between](http://jsfiddle.net/cwY6C/)" function. 
Why I can't use it directly on number? It is Number object whatsoever!

```
var a = 21;
21.between("( 16 20 ]"); // this is wrong and not working
//alert ( typeof 21 ) is number
a.between("( 16 20 ]");  // working
```

Comment: Interesting in the answers to see this can be done.  On a related note, I wrote a little web thing that uses a more structured approach to intervals and converting them to/from strings which you may be interested in: https://github.com/hostilefork/jquery-numband/blob/e15091d72f172b83f56b6f45e3f4aac4883a4420/jquery-numband.js#L9

Comment: I don't recommend extending the native prototypes. You might get a namespace conflict in a later version of javascript, and overwrite a standard method accidentally, confusing everyone around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
(21).between("( 16 20 ]");
```

When the parser (well, the lexer) sees "21." it thinks you've got a floating-point constant.  What also works (and what really looks icky to me personally) is:

```
21..between("( 16 20 ]");
```

Comment: @Brünnhilde yes that's correct. The language is happy to do that sort of thing, but it can't sometimes because the syntax gets in the way.